# Viewer for linked CSV files

Tags: csv, dataset, viewer

I have a dataset in several CSV files. The records have keys that map / link the files.

Excel runs into the million rows issue and Tad does not have linking between the files.

Google used to have a tool for large CSV files but it has probably been discontinued.

I want to explore the dataset or create summarized files. What is a / the best tool for such needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option I found was PowerPivot - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-pivot-powerful-data-analysis-and-data-modeling-in-excel-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045